# An error occurs when I use HTMLTestRunner module

Tags: python, python-unittest

i used unittest + HTMLTestRunner to test the software,early it runs very well,but yestarday i found it occured an error

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cephmgmtclient/sds_cli_auto_test/HTMLTestRunner.py", line 558, in complete_output
    return self.outputBuffer.getvalue()
AttributeError: '_TestResult' object has no attribute 'outputBuffer'
```

i searched the reason on internet,some people ask me to add the code in HTMLTestRunner.py and the code is below:

```
class _TestResult(TestResult):
    # note: _TestResult is a pure representation of results.
    # It lacks the output and reporting ability compares to unittest._TextTestResult.

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1):
        TestResult.__init__(self)
        self.stdout0 = None
        self.stderr0 = None
        self.success_count = 0
        self.failure_count = 0
        self.error_count = 0
        self.verbosity = verbosity

        # result is a list of result in 4 tuple
        # (
        #   result code (0: success; 1: fail; 2: error),
        #   TestCase object,
        #   Test output (byte string),
        #   stack trace,
        # )
        self.result = []
        self.outputBuffer = io.BytesIO()
        #self.test_start_time = round(time.time(), 2)
```

afer do this,it not occur the same error,but my test cases cannot run,when i python the case.py,the print is below

```
Begin to run test_template 1 and apply the job map

E  setUpClass (__main__.Test_case01)

Time Elapsed: 0:00:00.013564
```

it is so strange!because it normal in last version and i never changed my test case!
i can not figure out

the all codes of HTMLTestRunner.py is below

```
# TODO: color stderr
# TODO: simplify javascript using ,ore than 1 class in the class attribute?

import datetime
import StringIO
import sys
import time
import unittest
from xml.sax import saxutils


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The redirectors below are used to capture output during testing. Output
# sent to sys.stdout and sys.stderr are automatically captured. However
# in some cases sys.stdout is already cached before HTMLTestRunner is
# invoked (e.g. calling logging.basicConfig). In order to capture those
# output, use the redirectors for the cached stream.
#
# e.g.
#   >>> logging.basicConfig(stream=HTMLTestRunner.stdout_redirector)
#   >>>

class OutputRedirector(object):
    """ Wrapper to redirect stdout or stderr """
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp

    def write(self, s):
        self.fp.write(s)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        self.fp.writelines(lines)

    def flush(self):
        self.fp.flush()

stdout_redirector = OutputRedirector(sys.stdout)
stderr_redirector = OutputRedirector(sys.stderr)



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Template

class Template_mixin(object):
    """
    Define a HTML template for report customerization and generation.

    Overall structure of an HTML report

    HTML
    +------------------------+
    |<html>                  |
    |  <head>                |
    |                        |
    |   STYLESHEET           |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |  </head>               |
    |                        |
    |  <body>                |
    |                        |
    |   HEADING              |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |   REPORT               |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |   ENDING               |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |  </body>               |
    |</html>                 |
    +------------------------+
    """

    STATUS = {
    0: 'pass',
    1: 'fail',
    2: 'error',
    }

    DEFAULT_TITLE = 'Unit Test Report'
    DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION = ''

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # HTML Template

    HTML_TMPL = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>%(title)s</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="%(generator)s"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    %(stylesheet)s
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
output_list = Array();

/* level - 0:Summary; 1:Failed; 2:All */
function showCase(level) {
    trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        tr = trs[i];
        id = tr.id;
        if (id.substr(0,2) == 'ft') {
            if (level < 1) {
                tr.className = 'hiddenRow';
            }
            else {
                tr.className = '';
            }
        }
        if (id.substr(0,2) == 'pt') {
            if (level > 1) {
                tr.className = '';
            }
            else {
                tr.className = 'hiddenRow';
            }
        }
    }
}


function showClassDetail(cid, count) {
    var id_list = Array(count);
    var toHide = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tid0 = 't' + cid.substr(1) + '.' + (i+1);
        tid = 'f' + tid0;
        tr = document.getElementById(tid);
        if (!tr) {
            tid = 'p' + tid0;
            tr = document.getElementById(tid);
        }
        id_list[i] = tid;
        if (tr.className) {
            toHide = 0;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tid = id_list[i];
        if (toHide) {
            document.getElementById('div_'+tid).style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById(tid).className = 'hiddenRow';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(tid).className = '';
        }
    }
}


function showTestDetail(div_id){
    var details_div = document.getElementById(div_id)
    var displayState = details_div.style.display
    // alert(displayState)
    if (displayState != 'block' ) {
        displayState = 'block'
        details_div.style.display = 'block'
    }
    else {
        details_div.style.display = 'none'
    }
}


function html_escape(s) {
    s = s.replace(/&/g,'&amp;');
    s = s.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
    s = s.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
    return s;
}

/* obsoleted by detail in <div>
function showOutput(id, name) {
    var w = window.open("", //url
                    name,
                    "resizable,scrollbars,status,width=800,height=450");
    d = w.document;
    d.write("<pre>");
    d.write(html_escape(output_list[id]));
    d.write("\n");
    d.write("<a href='javascript:window.close()'>close</a>\n");
    d.write("</pre>\n");
    d.close();
}
*/
--></script>

%(heading)s
%(report)s
%(ending)s

</body>
</html>
"""
    # variables: (title, generator, stylesheet, heading, report, ending)


    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Stylesheet
    #
    # alternatively use a <link> for external style sheet, e.g.
    #   <link rel="stylesheet" href="$url" type="text/css">

    STYLESHEET_TMPL = """
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body        { font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 80%; }
table       { font-size: 100%; }
pre         { }

/* -- heading ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
h1 {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: gray;
}
.heading {
    margin-top: 0ex;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
}

.heading .attribute {
    margin-top: 1ex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.heading .description {
    margin-top: 2ex;
    margin-bottom: 4ex;
}

/* -- css div popup ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
a.popup_link {
}

a.popup_link:hover {
    color: red;
}

.popup_window {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    /*border: solid #627173 1px; */
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E6E6D6;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 500px;
}

}
/* -- report ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#show_detail_line {
    margin-top: 3ex;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
}
#result_table {
    width: 80%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#header_row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #777;
}
#result_table td {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 2px;
}
#total_row  { font-weight: bold; }
.passClass  { background-color: #6c6; }
.failClass  { background-color: #c60; }
.errorClass { background-color: #c00; }
.passCase   { color: #6c6; }
.failCase   { color: #c60; font-weight: bold; }
.errorCase  { color: #c00; font-weight: bold; }
.hiddenRow  { display: none; }
.testcase   { margin-left: 2em; }


/* -- ending ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ending {
}

</style>
"""



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Heading
    #

    HEADING_TMPL = """<div class='heading'>
<h1>%(title)s</h1>
%(parameters)s
<p class='description'>%(description)s</p>
</div>

""" # variables: (title, parameters, description)

    HEADING_ATTRIBUTE_TMPL = """<p class='attribute'><strong>%(name)s:</strong> %(value)s</p>
""" # variables: (name, value)



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Report
    #

    REPORT_TMPL = """
<p id='show_detail_line'>Show
<a href='javascript:showCase(0)'>Summary</a>
<a href='javascript:showCase(1)'>Failed</a>
<a href='javascript:showCase(2)'>All</a>
</p>
<table id='result_table'>
<colgroup>
<col align='left' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
</colgroup>
<tr id='header_row'>
    <td>Test Group/Test case</td>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
    <td>Error</td>
    <td>View</td>
</tr>
%(test_list)s
<tr id='total_row'>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>%(count)s</td>
    <td>%(Pass)s</td>
    <td>%(fail)s</td>
    <td>%(error)s</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
""" # variables: (test_list, count, Pass, fail, error)

    REPORT_CLASS_TMPL = r"""
<tr class='%(style)s'>
    <td>%(desc)s</td>
    <td>%(count)s</td>
    <td>%(Pass)s</td>
    <td>%(fail)s</td>
    <td>%(error)s</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:showClassDetail('%(cid)s',%(count)s)">Detail</a></td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (style, desc, count, Pass, fail, error, cid)


    REPORT_TEST_WITH_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
<tr id='%(tid)s' class='%(Class)s'>
    <td class='%(style)s'><div class='testcase'>%(desc)s</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>

    <!--css div popup start-->
    <a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_%(tid)s')" >
        %(status)s</a>

    <div id='div_%(tid)s' class="popup_window">
        <div style='text-align: right; color:red;cursor:pointer'>
        <a onfocus='this.blur();' onclick="document.getElementById('div_%(tid)s').style.display = 'none' " >
           [x]</a>
        </div>
        <pre>
        %(script)s
        </pre>
    </div>
    <!--css div popup end-->

    </td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (tid, Class, style, desc, status)


    REPORT_TEST_NO_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
<tr id='%(tid)s' class='%(Class)s'>
    <td class='%(style)s'><div class='testcase'>%(desc)s</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>%(status)s</td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (tid, Class, style, desc, status)


    REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
%(id)s: %(output)s
""" # variables: (id, output)



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # ENDING
    #

    ENDING_TMPL = """<div id='ending'>&nbsp;</div>"""

# -------------------- The end of the Template class -------------------


TestResult = unittest.TestResult

class _TestResult(TestResult):
    # note: _TestResult is a pure representation of results.
    # It lacks the output and reporting ability compares to unittest._TextTestResult.

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1):
        TestResult.__init__(self)
        self.stdout0 = None
        self.stderr0 = None
        self.success_count = 0
        self.failure_count = 0
        self.error_count = 0
        self.verbosity = verbosity

        # result is a list of result in 4 tuple
        # (
        #   result code (0: success; 1: fail; 2: error),
        #   TestCase object,
        #   Test output (byte string),
        #   stack trace,
        # )
        self.result = []


    def startTest(self, test):
        TestResult.startTest(self, test)
        # just one buffer for both stdout and stderr
        self.outputBuffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        stdout_redirector.fp = self.outputBuffer
        stderr_redirector.fp = self.outputBuffer
        self.stdout0 = sys.stdout
        self.stderr0 = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = stdout_redirector
        sys.stderr = stderr_redirector


    def complete_output(self):
        """
        Disconnect output redirection and return buffer.
        Safe to call multiple times.
        """
        if self.stdout0:
            sys.stdout = self.stdout0
            sys.stderr = self.stderr0
            self.stdout0 = None
            self.stderr0 = None
        return self.outputBuffer.getvalue()


    def stopTest(self, test):
        # Usually one of addSuccess, addError or addFailure would have been called.
        # But there are some path in unittest that would bypass this.
        # We must disconnect stdout in stopTest(), which is guaranteed to be called.
        self.complete_output()


    def addSuccess(self, test):
        self.success_count += 1
        TestResult.addSuccess(self, test)
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((0, test, output, ''))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('ok ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('.')

    def addError(self, test, err):
        self.error_count += 1
        TestResult.addError(self, test, err)
        _, _exc_str = self.errors[-1]
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((2, test, output, _exc_str))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('E  ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('E')

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        self.failure_count += 1
        TestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)
        _, _exc_str = self.failures[-1]
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((1, test, output, _exc_str))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('F  ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('F')


class HTMLTestRunner(Template_mixin):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, stream=sys.stdout, verbosity=1, title=None, description=None):
        self.stream = stream
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        if title is None:
            self.title = self.DEFAULT_TITLE
        else:
            self.title = title
        if description is None:
            self.description = self.DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION
        else:
            self.description = description

        self.startTime = datetime.datetime.now()


    def run(self, test):
        "Run the given test case or test suite."
        result = _TestResult(self.verbosity)
        test(result)
        self.stopTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.generateReport(test, result)
        print >>sys.stderr, '\nTime Elapsed: %s' % (self.stopTime-self.startTime)
        return result


    def sortResult(self, result_list):
        # unittest does not seems to run in any particular order.
        # Here at least we want to group them together by class.
        rmap = {}
        classes = []
        for n,t,o,e in result_list:
            cls = t.__class__
            if not rmap.has_key(cls):
                rmap[cls] = []
                classes.append(cls)
            rmap[cls].append((n,t,o,e))
        r = [(cls, rmap[cls]) for cls in classes]
        return r


    def getReportAttributes(self, result):
        """
        Return report attributes as a list of (name, value).
        Override this to add custom attributes.
        """
        startTime = str(self.startTime)[:19]
        duration = str(self.stopTime - self.startTime)
        status = []
        if result.success_count: status.append('Pass %s'    % result.success_count)
        if result.failure_count: status.append('Failure %s' % result.failure_count)
        if result.error_count:   status.append('Error %s'   % result.error_count  )
        if status:
            status = ' '.join(status)
        else:
            status = 'none'
        return [
            ('Start Time', startTime),
            ('Duration', duration),
            ('Status', status),
        ]


    def generateReport(self, test, result):
        report_attrs = self.getReportAttributes(result)
        generator = 'HTMLTestRunner %s' % __version__
        stylesheet = self._generate_stylesheet()
        heading = self._generate_heading(report_attrs)
        report = self._generate_report(result)
        ending = self._generate_ending()
        output = self.HTML_TMPL % dict(
            title = saxutils.escape(self.title),
            generator = generator,
            stylesheet = stylesheet,
            heading = heading,
            report = report,
            ending = ending,
        )
        self.stream.write(output.encode('utf8'))


    def _generate_stylesheet(self):
        return self.STYLESHEET_TMPL


    def _generate_heading(self, report_attrs):
        a_lines = []
        for name, value in report_attrs:
            line = self.HEADING_ATTRIBUTE_TMPL % dict(
                    name = saxutils.escape(name),
                    value = saxutils.escape(value),
                )
            a_lines.append(line)
        heading = self.HEADING_TMPL % dict(
            title = saxutils.escape(self.title),
            parameters = ''.join(a_lines),
            description = saxutils.escape(self.description),
        )
        return heading


    def _generate_report(self, result):
        rows = []
        sortedResult = self.sortResult(result.result)
        for cid, (cls, cls_results) in enumerate(sortedResult):
            # subtotal for a class
            np = nf = ne = 0
            for n,t,o,e in cls_results:
                if n == 0: np += 1
                elif n == 1: nf += 1
                else: ne += 1

            # format class description
            if cls.__module__ == "__main__":
                name = cls.__name__
            else:
                name = "%s.%s" % (cls.__module__, cls.__name__)
            doc = cls.__doc__ and cls.__doc__.split("\n")[0] or ""
            desc = doc and '%s: %s' % (name, doc) or name

            row = self.REPORT_CLASS_TMPL % dict(
                style = ne > 0 and 'errorClass' or nf > 0 and 'failClass' or 'passClass',
                desc = desc,
                count = np+nf+ne,
                Pass = np,
                fail = nf,
                error = ne,
                cid = 'c%s' % (cid+1),
            )
            rows.append(row)

            for tid, (n,t,o,e) in enumerate(cls_results):
                self._generate_report_test(rows, cid, tid, n, t, o, e)

        report = self.REPORT_TMPL % dict(
            test_list = ''.join(rows),
            count = str(result.success_count+result.failure_count+result.error_count),
            Pass = str(result.success_count),
            fail = str(result.failure_count),
            error = str(result.error_count),
        )
        return report


    def _generate_report_test(self, rows, cid, tid, n, t, o, e):
        # e.g. 'pt1.1', 'ft1.1', etc
        has_output = bool(o or e)
        tid = (n == 0 and 'p' or 'f') + 't%s.%s' % (cid+1,tid+1)
        name = t.id().split('.')[-1]
        doc = t.shortDescription() or ""
        desc = doc and ('%s: %s' % (name, doc)) or name
        tmpl = has_output and self.REPORT_TEST_WITH_OUTPUT_TMPL or self.REPORT_TEST_NO_OUTPUT_TMPL

        # o and e should be byte string because they are collected from stdout and stderr?
        if isinstance(o,str):
            # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
            # uo = unicode(o.encode('string_escape'))
            uo = o.decode('latin-1')
        else:
            uo = o
        if isinstance(e,str):
            # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
            # ue = unicode(e.encode('string_escape'))
            ue = e.decode('latin-1')
        else:
            ue = e

        script = self.REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL % dict(
            id = tid,
            output = saxutils.escape(uo+ue),
        )

        row = tmpl % dict(
            tid = tid,
            Class = (n == 0 and 'hiddenRow' or 'none'),
            style = n == 2 and 'errorCase' or (n == 1 and 'failCase' or 'none'),
            desc = desc,
            script = script,
            status = self.STATUS[n],
        )
        rows.append(row)
        if not has_output:
            return

    def _generate_ending(self):
        return self.ENDING_TMPL


##############################################################################
# Facilities for running tests from the command line
##############################################################################

# Note: Reuse unittest.TestProgram to launch test. In the future we may
# build our own launcher to support more specific command line
# parameters like test title, CSS, etc.
class TestProgram(unittest.TestProgram):
    """
    A variation of the unittest.TestProgram. Please refer to the base
    class for command line parameters.
    """
    def runTests(self):
        # Pick HTMLTestRunner as the default test runner.
        # base class's testRunner parameter is not useful because it means
        # we have to instantiate HTMLTestRunner before we know self.verbosity.
        if self.testRunner is None:
            self.testRunner = HTMLTestRunner(verbosity=self.verbosity)
        unittest.TestProgram.runTests(self)

main = TestProgram

##############################################################################
# Executing this module from the command line
##############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(module=None)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code around `HTMLTestRunner.py", line 558, in complete_output`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but unless you have a reason not to, I would suggest using Python 3. And then call `super().__init__()` instead of `TestResult.__init__(self)`.

Comment: What does the code look like a line 558?

Comment: here is the output in code:    548     def complete_output(self):
    549         """
    550         Disconnect output redirection and return buffer.
    551         Safe to call multiple times.
    552         """
    553         if self.stdout0:
    554             sys.stdout = self.stdout0
    555             sys.stderr = self.stderr0
    556             self.stdout0 = None
    557             self.stderr0 = None
    558         return self.outputBuffer.getvalue()
    559

Comment: i put all the code in this page@ Kent Shikama

Comment: thanks everyone for asking the question

Answer (score 0):

at last i add a line in _TestResult() function,and the code is below

```
class _TestResult(TestResult):
    # note: _TestResult is a pure representation of results.
    # It lacks the output and reporting ability compares to unittest._TextTestResult.

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1):
        TestResult.__init__(self)
        self.stdout0 = None
        self.stderr0 = None
        self.success_count = 0
        self.failure_count = 0
        self.error_count = 0
        self.verbosity = verbosity

        # result is a list of result in 4 tuple
        # (
        #   result code (0: success; 1: fail; 2: error),
        #   TestCase object,
        #   Test output (byte string),
        #   stack trace,
        # )
        self.result = []
        self.outputBuffer = StringIO.StringIO() #this the added code!!!
```

and my program occur error because another place the code is wrong ,i fixed it !
so it works add the code!